# How to fix C# Roslyn Monodevelop-Dnx-Addin on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, monodevelop, dnx

This morning we learned that this project
https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-dnx-addin/tree/roslyn
would allow developers to load and restore project.json's through Ubuntu Linux monodevelop and the Roslyn csc compiler and allow their compilation, call stack argument inspection and executable execution in the coreclr and corefx runtime environment.

The following steps from https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-dnx-addin/tree/roslyn have errors in them

Building from source
From the src directory run NuGet restore.

```
git clone git@github.com:mono/monodevelop.git
cd monodevelop
git checkout roslyn
git submodule update --init --recursive
make
rm -rf main/build/tests/
cd ..

git clone https://github.com/mhutch/MonoDevelop.AddinMaker
cd MonoDevelop.AddinMaker
nuget restore MonoDevelop.AddinMaker.sln
make install /p:MDBinDir=../monodevelop/main/build/bin /p:MDProfileVersion=6.0
```

*** The above line results in No rule to make target `install'.Stop. ***

```
git clone git@github.com:mrward/monodevelop-dnx-addin.git
cd monodevelop-dnx-addins
git checkout roslyn
cd src
nuget restore MonoDevelop.Dnx.sln
xbuild MonoDevelop.Dnx.sln /p:MDProfileVersion=6.0 /p:MDBinDir=../../../monodevelop/main/build/bin
```

The above line results in the C# compiler error : /opt/mono-2015.12.10+23.35.44/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.CSharp.targets (CoreCompile target) ->

```
MonoDevelop.Dnx/DnxProjectService.cs(139,20): error CS0117: `MonoDevelop.Ide.DispatchService' does not contain a definition for `GuiDispatch'
```

The last xbuild step can be replaced by opening the MonoDevelop.Dnx.sln into Xamarin Studio 6.0 and building the solution.

When the above line  is executed on Monodevelop 6.0, it results in an Unhandled Exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
>           File name: 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'***

Please help us correct these errors.

Comment: I was able to download the Monodevelop 5.7 1.2.1 AddInMaker for Linux just now called MonoDevelop.AddinMaker-1.2.1.mpack . May I ask if this shortens the build process? Please use this link, http://addins.monodevelop.com/Project/Index/87.

Comment: May I ask if  downloading MonoDevelop.AddinMaker-1.2.1.mpack   saves the step of creating the addin .mpack file by running:

mdtool.exe setup pack bin/merged/MonoDevelop.Dnx.dll?

Comment: When I install the MonoDevelop.AddinMaker-1.2.1.mpack as a file using the Monodevelopment add-in manager, I get the error message: The selected add-ins cannot be installed because there are dependency conflicts. The package ::Monodevelop .Ide v5.7 could not be found in any repository., The package ::Monodevelop .Cor v5.7 could not be found in any repository., and the Install button is greyed out. How do we handle that error message?

Comment: I built and installed the MonoDevelop.AddinMaker-1.2.1.mpack for Monodevelop 6.0 just now. However when I follow these instructions: git clone git@github.com:mrward/monodevelop-dnx-addin.git
cd monodevelop-dnx-addins
git checkout roslyn
cd src
nuget restore MonoDevelop.Dnx.sln
xbuild MonoDevelop.Dnx.sln /p:MDProfileVersion=6.0 /p:MDBinDir=../../../monodevelop/main/build/bin
I get the following C# compiler error: MonoDevelop.Dnx/DnxProjectService.cs(139,20): error CS0117: MonoDevelop.Ide.DispatchService' does not contain a definition forGuiDispatch' How do we fix this C# compiler error?

Comment: The DispatchService error is because the latest code on MonoDevelop's master branch has changed and the DNX addin has not been updated. Not sure about the other error - that is not a compilation error. Can you compile any C# project in MonoDevelop 6.0?

Comment: @Matt Ward, Yes, I can compile any C# project in MonoDevelop 6.0 which has the correct assembly references.

Comment: @Matt Ward, When I Git clone into git@github.com:mrward/monodevelop-dnx-addin.git, I get the Permission Denied error message shown here: git clone git@github.com:mrward/monodevelop-dnx-addin.git
Cloning into 'monodevelop-dnx-addin'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
How do we fix the Permission denied problem?

Comment: There is no difference in the contents of git@github.com:mrward/monodevelop-dnx-addin.git compared to https://github.com/monodevelop-dnx-addin
https://github.com/monodevelop-dnx-addin. The only difference is only in the directory structures. I was able to build and install MonoDevelop.Dnx_0.1.mpack
into Monodevelop 6.0 for Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS. Please show me how to use new capability.

Comment: @Matt Ward, I am replacing DispatchService.GuiDispatch with Runtime.RunInMainThread (delegate{} );

Comment: @richpe - the addin has been updated to work with latest monodevelop.

Comment: @Matt Ward,Thank you for updating the monodevelop-dnx-addin to work with the latest monodevelop. How do we use your monodevelop-dnx-addin capability which I just built and installed on Monodevelop 6.0 for Ubuntu Linux to create DNX projects?

Comment: What does it mean to migrate existing projects to the Addin Maker using the following steps?

Add {86F6BF2A-E449-4B3E-813B-9ACC37E5545F} to the project's flavor GUIDs i.e. for C#: <ProjectTypeGuids>{86F6BF2A-E449-4B3E-813B-9ACC37E5545F};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
Add a reference to the NuGet package monodevelop.addins
Remove all references you have to the assemblies included with MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio.
Remove all addin dependency declarations from your manifests and assembly attributes.
Add Addin References for all of the dependencies you remvoed in step 4.

Comment: @Matt Ward, If you have the time, please answer this Stack Overflow question in your own sentences.

Comment: @Matt Ward, My manager wants to know if the Monodevelop Dnx Addin will lets us debug C# managed code with symbols or not?

Comment: There is limited debugger support. If mono 4.3 is installed you can hit breakpoints. Debugging when running with the .net core CLR is not supported though only when running with mono.

Comment: @Matt Ward, Please let me know what is meant by "Debugging when running with the .net core CLR is not supported though only when running with mono." Thank you.

Comment: @Matt Ward, Please help me with this possible error on my part:. When I create a new ASPNET5 DNX project in Monodevelop 6.0 using the moodevelop-dnx-addin,I get an orange dialog box saying "Unable to initialize DNX project system. The specified runtime path '1.0.0-rc1-update1' does not exist. Searched locations /home/venkat/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-mono.1.0.0-rc1-update1
/home/venkat/.dnx/runtimes/kre-mono.1.0.0-rc1-update1. 
/home/venkat/.dnx/packages/KRE-Mono.1.0.0-rc1-update1
/home/venkat/dnx/runtimes/dnx-mono.1.0.0-rc1-update1
  at MonoDevelop.Dnx.DnxProjectService.LoadDnxProjectSystem

Comment: You can run DNX apps with two runtimes - mono or .net core. Debugging only works if the DNX app is run with mono.

Comment: You need to install the latest DNX runtime yourself. Go to get.asp.net for more information

Comment: @Matt Ward, I traced the problem to this member function in DnxPaths.cs,                                                                                             private IEnumerable<string> GetRuntimePathsFromVersionOrAlias(string versionOrAlias, string runtimePath)
 {
 // Newer format
 yield return GetRuntimePathFromVersionOrAlias(versionOrAlias, runtimePath, ".dnx", "dnx-mono.{0}", "dnx-clr-win-x86.{0}", "runtimes");         // New format
    }. In addition, when I build the DNX project, my custom prebuild MonoDevelop step is stuck forever at DNU restore. Please advise us.

Comment: You need to install the dnx runtime.

Comment: @Matt Ward,  I totally agree with you that we  need to install the latest DNX runtime ourselves.

Comment: @Matt Ward, I will install the latest dnx runtime now. May we chat in 15 minutes?

Comment: @Matt Ward, May we update our installed DNX Runtime with  the latest prebuild binaries

Prebuild binaries for ASP.NET 5 are available (.tar.gz) and can be installed as appropriate based on your system configuration

Comment: @Matt Ward, My manager is worried about "me knocking out our existing mono and DNX" by by purging the previous installed version and sudo apt-get installing the latest DNX Runtime. Is there a way to resolve this problem?

Comment: @Matt Ward, After installing mono-complete and dnx, when I build the DNX project, my RebuildHelloWorld MonoDevelop step is stuck over 2 minures at DNU restore. Is this okay?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98352/discussion-between-matt-ward-and-frank).

Answer (score 0):

Matt Ward fixed the C# compiler error having to do with MonoDevelop.Ide.DispatchService.GuiDispatch() in the following steps a few hours ago.

```
git clone git@github.com:mrward/monodevelop-dnx-addin.git
cd monodevelop-dnx-addins
git checkout roslyn
cd src
nuget restore MonoDevelop.Dnx.sln
xbuild MonoDevelop.Dnx.sln /p:MDProfileVersion=6.0 /p:MDBinDir=../../../monodevelop/main/build/bin
```

The solution to the second broken step was found in  this URL, https://github.com/mhutch/MonoDevelop.AddinMaker#installation where I ran the following step:                                                      `./Install.sh /p:MDBinDir=../monodevelop/main/build/bin /p:MDProfileVersion=6.0.`

Comment: I just created a simple monodevelop addin after reading this URL: www.monodevelop.com/developers/articles/creating-a-simple-add-in. How do I extend this concept to an Monodevelop DNX addin with a project.json?

Comment: I observe that there are Console templates in Matt Ward's Monodevelop DNX addin project. How might we use these templates?

Comment: I just noticed that our Monodevelop 6.0 built for Ubuntu Linux has a Monosoft DNX debugger as well as Microsoft .NET DNX debugger. Is it possible for us to use either one?

Comment: I just created an ASPNET 5 DNX project using the Ubuntu Linux version of Monodevelop 6.0.